# How to get current directory of a specific drive in Visual Studio Express 2013(C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am porting a program from Borland C++ Builder to Visual Studio 2013 (C++). The program uses getcurdir to get the current directory of a drive. This function has a parameter drive, but the Microsoft equivalent function getcwd don't have such parameter. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged visual studio, I assume you'r using windows. Beside that current directory is just one, (i.e. where the executable is located or other if you've moved to) current directory won't be different depending on current drive, I think. Then, in windows you may use the function `GetCurrentDirectory` from winapi. The prototype is:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetCurrentDirectory(
  _In_   DWORD nBufferLength,
  _Out_  LPTSTR lpBuffer
);
```

You may get details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Example:

```
TCHAR cwd[100];
GetCurrentDirectory(100,cwd);
// now cwd will contain absolute path to current directory
```

Answer (score 0):

(Yes I know this is an old entry, just for the records if somebody stumbles over the same issue...)

As [deeiip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1819107/deeiip) already said correctly, in Windows there is only 1 current directory, but cmd.exe fakes DOS behavior when there was 1 *current directory per drive*.

If you need to access cmd's *current directory per drive*, use the according hidden environment variables, e.g. "%=C:%".

Here an example application (in C#):

```
using System;

static class Module1 {

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        var myFolder = GetCurrentFolderPerDrive(args[0]); //e.g. "C:"
        Console.WriteLine(myFolder);
    }

    private static string GetCurrentFolderPerDrive(string driveLetter) {
        driveLetter = NormalizeDriveLetter(driveLetter);
        string myEnvironmentVariable = $"%={driveLetter}%";
        string myResult = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(myEnvironmentVariable);
        if (myResult == myEnvironmentVariable) return $"{driveLetter.ToUpperInvariant()}\\"; //No current folder set, return root
        return myResult;
    }

    private static String NormalizeDriveLetter(String driveLetter) {
        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(driveLetter)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(driveLetter), "The drive letter is null, empty or white-space.");
        Boolean throwException = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".IndexOf(driveLetter[0]) < 0);
        if (!throwException) {
            if (driveLetter.Length == 1) {
                driveLetter += ':';
            } else if (driveLetter.Length != 2) {
                throwException = true;
            }
        }
        if (throwException) throw new ArgumentException($"A well-formed drive letter expected, e.g. \"C:\"!\r\nGiven value: \"{driveLetter}\".", nameof(driveLetter));
        return driveLetter;
    }

}
```